# Assign border to multiple JLabels

Tags: java, swing, border, jlabel

I have 10 `JLabels` which I want to have the same border. It is a number that is manageable by hand but to grow as a programmer I want to know if there is a way to make this easier.

I have tried with a for each loop that goes true all the components of the panel the labels are on, and then use the method `setBorder(...)`. But this doesn't work obviously because the objects are recognized as Components instead of JLabels.

How do I automate the border assignment to a `JLabel`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer provided by [@Atreys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941396/assign-border-to-multiple-jlabels/6941468#6941468) will suffice, but *there's more than one way to skin a cat*. Another option would be to create a class that extends `JLabel` and assigns a border within its constructor. Therefore, all instances will have the same border, as per your request. This will also avoid having to clumsily iterate over a collection of `Component`s, use the `instanceof` operator, and then typecast, which isn't really OOP.

---

```
public final class BorderedJLabel extends JLabel{
    public BorderedJLabel(){
        // assign border
    }
}
```

---

## Addendum:

And if you wanted to avoid the verbosity of having to type `new BorderedJLabel()` for each new `BorderedJLabel` instance, you could peruse a *static factory method*, as such

```
public final class BorderedJLabel extends JLabel{
    private BorderedJLabel(){
        // assign border
    }

    public static final BorderedJLabel newInstance(){
        return new BorderedJLabel();
    }
}
```

Given this design, you'll be able to create new `BorderedJLabel` instances more succinctly by simply typing `BorderedJLabel.newInstance()`.

Comment: For every way you want to construct a JLabel, you'll need to add an appropriate way to construct a MyJLabel.  This would be a more OOP way to solve the problem, but potentially take more work, and if you forget you have the MyJLabel class, and use the JLabel 'by mistake', you won't get the border set.

Comment: +1: This approach allows you to have unbordered `JLabel`s on your components as well.

Comment: This is indeed a better approach, I will use this one as it's more object oriented.

Comment: +1 this is a textbook case for subclassing, although may I respectfully suggest the class is called `BorderedJLabel`. Creating all the constructors takes 1 click on "Create constructors from superclass" on the Eclipse create class wizard.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have the solution, almost.

Iterate through all the components of the panel, and if one is a JLabel, cast it and set the border:

```
for (Component comp : componentList) {
    if (comp instanceof JLabel) {
        ((JLabel)comp).setBorder(myBorder());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, the cast was missing then. Thank you very much!

Comment: I also like your answer because you handed me the missing pieces of how I wanted to fix it originally.